# Black screen after resuming from hibernate (Windows)

Tags: windows, sleep, hibernate, powersave

I have this problem both on Windows 10 and Windows 8.1: when I resume my computer after being hibernated it works but my screen remains black, then, if I press the power button (configured to suspend the computer) it goes to suspend mode and after resuming the screen works again.

It is like my graphics card is not being waked correctly (AMD 7790).

The event viewer shows no errors, just information about the computer entering on a low power state and then waking up.

Comment: Did you recently update any drivers?

Comment: On Windows 10 I'm using a clean install, on Windows 8.1 I've updated drivers many times, always with the same problem.

Comment: Same exact thing happens for me, and a quick standby resume sometimes does the magic, and sometimes I had to hard restart. Plus i get **Your computer is low on memory** though obviously there's no program that hogs RAM. Mine's a GTX1070 with 16GBDDR4 RAM on Windows 10 Creators Update fresh install -> This means its not got anything to do with graphic drivers since we have different cards